# R binary exhaustive list without for loop

Tags: r, for-loop, matrix, combinations, permutation

I am trying to come up with every possible combination of a set number of 1's and 0's in a list, without any overlap.  I want the list to contain a series of matrices.

I have come up with the following code, which accomplishes that goal, for example if you want 2 values of 1 and 2 of 0 in a 2x2 matrix:

```
z<-0
 for(i in 1:(4-1)){
   for(j in (i+1):(4)){
     x<-rep(0,4)
     x[c(i,j)]<-1
     x<-matrix(x,nrow=2,byrow=TRUE)
     z<-z+1
     k[[z]]<-x
}}
```

This is fine, but I would like to be able to create lists involving a larger number of 0's and 1's.

The only way I know how to do this is to nest more and more for loops

For example, in order to print every non-repetitive combination of 3 1's in 9 total spaces in a 3x3 matrix:

```
for(i in 1:(9-2)){
for(j in (i+1):(9-1)){
for(k in (j+1):9){
x<-rep(0,9)
x[c(i,j,k)]<-1
x<-matrix(x,nrow=3,byrow=TRUE)
print(x)
}}}
```

I feel like there must be a more elegant and quicker solution(especially when dealing with larger numbers of digits).  Even if a simple solution could just give me vectors, it'd be easy enough to make them a list of matrices.  I would like variable amounts of 1's and 0's enumerated in a list so that I can use them for further manipulation.

Thank you for your help!

Comment: hope the below helps. Beware permn becomes very computational intensive in case of big vectors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a function to do it. The first argument is the size of the sides of the matrix, the second is the number of ones wanted:

```
makematrix <- function(n, k){
  z <- as.data.frame(t(expand.grid(rep(list(c(0,1)), n * n))))
  z <- z[ ,colSums(z) == k]
  lapply(z, function(x){matrix(x, nrow = n)})
}
```

First we make all the combinations of 0 and 1 in a data frame using `expand.grid`, subset by the ones with the correct number of 1s, then we rearrange them into a list of matrices using `lapply`.

```
makematrix(2, 2)
$V4
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    1    0
[2,]    1    0

$V6
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    1    1
[2,]    0    0

$V7
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    0    1
[2,]    1    0

$V10
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    1    0
[2,]    0    1

$V11
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    0    0
[2,]    1    1

$V13
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    0    1
[2,]    0    1
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also directly use library `combinat`, which `permn` function giving a direct list:

```
library(combinat)

unique(permn(c(1,1,0,0),function(x) matrix(x,nrow=sqrt(length(x)))))

#[[1]]
#     [,1] [,2]
#[1,]    1    0
#[2,]    1    0

#[[2]]
#     [,1] [,2]
#[1,]    1    1
#[2,]    0    0

#[[3]]
#    [,1] [,2]
#[1,]    0    1
#[2,]    1    0

#[[4]]
#     [,1] [,2]
#[1,]    0    0
#[2,]    1    1

#[[5]]
#     [,1] [,2]
#[1,]    1    0
#[2,]    0    1

#[[6]]
#     [,1] [,2]
#[1,]    0    1
#[2,]    0    1
```